# some queries in coredata?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm new at using CoreData and I'm trying to understand how to perform a query on a table. 
I have two doubts.Suppose i have two tables(say admin and 'stdDetails'),One contains admin profile(username,password etc) ie only one row and other contains student details(id,name,class etc)
 I want to fetch the admin password and also want to log all student names from 2nd table.
Is there any easy way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have a relationship between the two tables you'll have to do separate fetch requests.

Edit Fetch Request example:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc ] init ];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"stdDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext ];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity ];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [ self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return objects;
```

Comment: Thank you.I know that.I am asking about those two requests

Comment: i used above code .Then i got like this    objects (
    "<Details: 0x6d1cee0> (entity: Details; id: 0x6d31be0 <x-coredata://BFBBC0CC-B54B-4F62-9EA3-984D56191385/Details/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Details: 0x6d21050> (entity: Details; id: 0x6d34550 <x-coredata://BFBBC0CC-B54B-4F62-9EA3-984D56191385/Details/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Details: 0x6d1def0> (entity: Details; id: 0x6d08570 <x-coredata://BFBBC0CC-B54B-4F62-9EA3-984D56191385/Details/p3> ; data: <fault>)" )

Comment: The NSArray returns NSManagedObjects, you need to convert them to your details class so you can access it's properties.

Comment: Ok it works fine.Is there any way to log a specific column completely without using for loop